# Rolling back needs more sanity checking

Tags: feature-request, rollbacks

Somehow, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/1612/1) was submitted with no tags. It's entirely possible that it got tagged with just a really crappy tag that got blasted away from orbit, leaving it completely naked. Eww.

Anyway, a few hours later Kevin came for the rescue and granted that question some badly needed tagging. The question sit mostly quiet until Thomas attempted to consume the data dump and stumbled on this corner case.

What kind of concerned me however is that it is possible to rollback the change and bring back the question to taglessnes<sup>so don't do that</sup> yes but <sup>just don't do that</sup> but it's a bu<sup>seriously don't do that it's that simple</sup> but what if somebody els<sup>it's on the homepage, people will catch it</sup> but it breaks inline editi<sup>who cares, rollback the rollback</sup> but I need my precious meta reps!<sup>sigh, fine...</sup>

So, er... perhaps the rolling back procedure needs a little more sanity checking, ranging from "does this revision of the question even have tags" to "if you were to submit this exact question today would the system accept it?"

Comment: I want to know how that even happened.  I thought the system added the "untagged" tag whenever it left a question with no tags.